# How to fix 'Unable to load class 'com.android.ide.common.repository.GradleVersion'.' in Android Studio Version 4.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio

I got the below error message when I run the project. I update the Gradle file, but the issue is not fixed.

I already followed that mention steps.

1. Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network).
2. Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)

[image]

Comment: click on `Re download...`

Comment: I already followed those steps.

Comment: Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network) and Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)

Comment: hello any solution here?